Can I customise the Excel ribbon so that a particular button always has its description visible?
I'm using Excel 365 (specifically, Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20346) 64-bit). When I open a blank workbook in a non-maximized window, the Data tab looks like this:

I've highlighted the Remove Duplicates button.
I have enormous difficulty remembering where this button is. Is there any way I can customise the ribbon so that it always shows its text?
I see that as the window is sized larger, eventually it shows its text:

but I want it to always show its text, or at least for it (rather than Text to Columns) to be the first one to show its text, when size permits.
The Customize the Ribbon dialog doesn't seem to offer anything I can actually do to it.

You could add a new ribbon Group, name it "Remove Duplicates", and add the Remove Duplicates command button to the group as the only button.
